# Convert to NHibernate Queryover

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

How do I convert following SQL to NH Queryover,

```
select COUNT(*)
from
(select p.CODE,sl.BATCH from STORELOCATION sl
right join PRODUCT p on p.CODE = sl.CODE
group by p.CODE,sl.BATCHID)
as t
```

Comment: Actually this is more simplified version of the query I want, the basic idea is to get the row count of a query with multiple groupings to use it for paging. I have no idea how to get the inner query part to work, that is why this question is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to achieve this using a custom projection, if anyone interested code is as follows,

```
[Serializable]
    public class GroupCountProjection : SimpleProjection
    {
        private PropertyProjection[] _projections;

        public GroupCountProjection(PropertyProjection[] projections)
        {
            _projections = projections;
        }

        public override bool IsAggregate
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
        {
            return new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 };
        }

        public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int position, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
        {
            SqlStringBuilder result = new SqlStringBuilder()
                .Add(" count(*) as y")
                .Add(position.ToString())
                .Add("_ from ( select ");
            for (int index = 0; index < _projections.Length; index++)
            {
                PropertyProjection projection = _projections[index];
                if (index > 0)
                    result.Add(",");
                result.Add(projection.ToSqlString(criteria, ++position, criteriaQuery, enabledFilters));
            }
            result.Add(" ");
            return result.ToSqlString();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "select count(*)";
        }

        public override bool IsGrouped
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override SqlString ToGroupSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery,
                                                   IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
        {
            SqlStringBuilder result = new SqlStringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < _projections.Length; index++)
            {
                PropertyProjection projection = _projections[index];
                if (index > 0)
                    result.Add(",");
                result.Add(StringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(projection.ToSqlString(criteria, 0, criteriaQuery,enabledFilters)));
            }
            result.Add(") as tbly");
            return result.ToSqlString();
        }
    }
```

here, the constructor of the projection needs to be passed with all the group by projections like,

```
var countQuery = GetProductQuery(); // this is the queryover 
            countQuery
                .Select(new GroupCountProjection(new[]{
                    Projections.Group(() => _productAlias.Code),
                    Projections.Group(() => _storeLocationAlias.Batch),
                 }));
int resultCount = (int)countQuery.List<object>().SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to solve it using QueryOver and Alias; sorry, but I can't test this code now. :(

```
        ProductModel myProd = null;
        StoreLocationModel myLocation = null;

        var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<ProductModel>(() => myProd)
            .JoinAlias(() => myProd.Locations, () => myLocation, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Select(Projections.GroupProperty(myProd.CODE), Projections.GroupProperty(myLocation.BATCHID))
            .RowCount();
```

I hope it's helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, The SQL generated by this does not have the Group By section, It give the total row count which is different from the no of rows returned with group by clause.

Comment: @Adipa Gunasekara: Ok, try to use .Select(Projections.Group(() => myProd.CODE), Projections.Group(() => myLocation.BATCHID)). I'm sorry but I can't try it again :(

Comment: It also gives the same results without group by section, I have tried this with quite a lot of different combinations but as soon as I try to get the rowCount the group by clause is goes missing in the query, so I believe only way to do this is to execute query as inner query as I have suggested in the question, still I do not have clear idea if it's even possible with NH Queryover.